# Bluetooth paring

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is there a possibility to force dialog show to user for entering a PIN.

I have a barcode reader, that on server side (I think), and he need to get a PIN code. But the problem is that all androids up 2.2 don't won't to show dialog. (The 2.2. show dialog and the pairing are ok).

In my code I reach discovering devices, and the next step is a paring.

I will be thankful for give me some explanations

Answer (score 0):

A Simple answer would be **NO**, It can't be possible to force user in `PIN dialog` as it is system generated.

You may create your own System checking for bluetooth pairing. A BroadCastReceiver will help you in this matter.